# FallbackResource in subdirectory

Tags: rewrite, apache-2.4

I manage a large number of PHP applications using [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)s and the following htaccess file:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Yes, that is the entire file (for each application)!

However, a few of the sites are in subfolders, necessitating the following change:

```
FallbackResource /subfolder/index.php
```

As you could probably guess, the `/` at the beginning means that the path is relative to the site/vhost, and here the path needs to be relative to the directory.

(If I were using `mod_rewrite` for this instead of `mod_dir`, I would have to add a `RewriteBase` to each subdirectory as needed, in a similar fashion.)

I thought that I could get around this by doing:

```
FallbackResource index.php # No slash!
```

However, when the site's rewrites contain slashes, for example, if the application is `/store/` and the path within it is `products/1234`, then Apache looks for `/store/products/index.php` instead of `/store/index.php` and returns a 500 with the following message in the log:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I would have thought that the `FallbackResource` path is relative to the .htaccess file in which it is configured, but it seems that it is actually relative to the requested URL.

Is there a way to have `FallbackResource` act the way that I expected?

---

I can use it the way it is if that's the answer, but it would make it a lot easier to manage the sites that I have if this can be done.  The sites use the same basic code with different themes and database connections, and the way it works now I have to modify the htaccess file every time we deploy a new version of the code (because it is checked into Git).  If we can make it that someone doesn't have to remember to make this modification every time, that would be really great.

Comment: Relative URLs are almost always bad news. You generally should avoid them when possible, and avoid site designs which encourage or even require them (such as using subdirectories instead of subdomains for unrelated content).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know they're bad. All of our new sites are in subdomains.  But I still have to support legacy sites this way (I don't have control over DNS for some of them), and I'm trying to find a way to make that easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sites about which I originally asked this question are no longer live, but here's what i ended up doing.

I ended up moving these sites to a server running Nginx, where all configuration is done in the config files of the server using a `try_files` directive. It was much easier to manage that way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible to do easily. I've tried various combinations of `DirectoryMatch` and `LocationMatch` in the main configuration files using the newish variable interpolation available in these two directives.

Although something like `FallBackResource index.html` is entirely valid configuration, I share Michael Hampton's concern that any use of relative URLs can cause problems. In the case of `FallBackResource index.html` for a particular directory tree, index.html must **always** be present otherwise you will get the recursion loop you describe for requests where `index.html` cannot be found.

In your case you would need a top level `.htaccess` file with `FallBackResource /index.html`, then `FallBackResource /subfoldername/index.html` in each relevant sub folder.

A simple script to generate these is probably safest.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn't really help. The issue here is not handling the lack of presence a file, but forwarding all unmatched requests to a PHP application. The question is because some PHP applications reside in a subfolder.

Comment: Well change `index.html` to `index.php` or whatever your controller script is (Sorry, I was just pasting my local test config). I still think it will work. Otherwise you'll need to use mod_rewrite :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe a work around using `DirectoryIndex` instead of `FallbackResource` might also work. The following will match `/a/script/` to the file `/some/path/to/a/script/index.py` then  `/some/path/to/a/script/index.html` then `/some/path/to/subfolder/index.py` and  finally `/some/path/index.py`. This relies upon `DirectoryIndex` honouring absolute paths.

```
ScriptAlias / "/some/path/to/"
<Directory "/some/path/to/">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .py
  DirectoryIndex index.py index.html 
  # Appending  /index.py seems to work whereas FallbackResource does not
  DirectoryIndex /subfolder/index.py
  DirectoryIndex /index.py
  FallbackResource /index.py
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Repeated calls to `DirectoryIndex` are appended to previous calls. In my case `FallbackResource` was not working and i stumbled upon this as a solution. The above is for CGI/Python files but I believe it will work in your scenario as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### *Aside:* Solution using mod_rewrite

Using mod_rewrite you can avoid the dependency (hard-coding) of the parent directory.

> (If I were using `mod_rewrite` for this instead of `mod_dir`, I would have to add a `RewriteBase` to each subdirectory as needed, in a similar fashion.)

You would *not* need to add `RewriteBase` here. In fact, you should avoid adding a `RewriteBase` directive in this scenario. (Don't copy the stock WordPress front-controller pattern.) And then use a ***relative** substitution* string (in the `RewriteRule` directive) to the front-controller. Relative *substitution* strings are relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. So, this is certainly an acceptable workaround to using `FallbackResource` that avoids having a dependence on the parent directory, if you are prepared to use mod_rewrite.

And if you are already using mod_rewrite for other rewrites then using mod_rewrite for the front-controller pattern as well is arguably the preferred solution anyway.

The mod_rewrite solution is used in combination with mod_dir's `DirectoryIndex`. Requests for the "root" directory itself are handled by mod_dir, not mod_rewrite. (That is, "root" of the application - the subdirectory - not necessarily the "document root" of the vHost.)

For example, with everything (including `index.php` and `.htaccess`) located inside the `/subfolder` directory:

```
# /subfolder/.htaccess

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The first `RewriteRule` directive is simply an optimisation and is not strictly necessary to make it "work". This rule avoids an unnecessary filesystem check after having rewritten the request to `index.php`. Alternatively, on Apache 2.4, you can use the `END` flag instead of `L` on the last rule.

In the absence of a `RewriteBase` directive, the last `RewriteRule` directive (that uses a *relative* substitution string) rewrites the request to `/subfolder/index.php` (the directory in which the `.htaccess` file is located).

---

Even in situations when you do need to know the name of the parent directory, this can be calculated, again using mod_rewrite.